# Saving cookies for voting ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cookies, voting

My problem is simple yet I couldn't find the best solution to it.

I want to know if someone voted on a post ON PAGE LOAD (not when they vote) and if they did, change the voting image so that they can see they already voted on it.

Best solution that came to my mind was to save cookies, first question is "is it good practice to save cookies and loop through all posts to find if cookie exists?"

second question is: if it is a good solution, what should be the way to save cookies? Since only registered members will be able to vote, keeping username and postId should be enough.. or not?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when the cookie is cleared? Should the user still see that he already voted? If he should, then a cookie probably isn't the best solution.

Comment: I'll be keeping votes on db too. This is just for client side.

Comment: Well for cookies, what you say is impossible but if it is possible, yes that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the browser, cookies have a size limit so this may not be the best approach.

You mention that you are keeping the votes in the DB.  When the page is requested just look at that table and send the appropriate image down.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are keeping the votes in a database, the best approach would be to determine if the vote occurred on the server-side and create the page accordingly.

Javascript can be used on the client side to asynchronously update the database and the GUI when a vote is cast (much like what **stackoverflow** does when we vote here).

Comment: I'm using JSON to update images, thats not a problem. So getting the right image or VOTED || NOTVOTED from db is the best approach?

Comment: If it was my project, I would use two static images in a Content directory, one for Voted and one for NotVoted, and write javascript to update the source of the image whenever the user clicks on Vote. That image would then be used as the default the next time he visits the page (this would be done with a server-side variable). You shouldn't need to get the image from the DB.

Comment: I'm not getting the image from db. you voted yesterday and you are viewing the site today. how do you display the correct image if you voted?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Ajax/ JQuery to update your images. Use WebMethods

Comment: In your question you mentioned "change the voting image so that they can see they already voted on it.", please check it.